# Unzip Multi Archive file's in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, unzip

I want to UnZip Zip File in my application for iPad.
For make this i found in different topic (in stackoverflow ^^) the package minizip.
But my problem is how UnZip multi archive like .zip.001, .zip.002, etc...?

If you need more information ask me.

Thanks in advance for your consideration.

Comment: Refer [HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org) uses this type of file format when departed a zip or rar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: if the file naming is `.zip.001` then it's not actually a multi-file zip archive. The file is simply split into several files and the only thing you have to do is put them together. A multi-file zip archive would be named `.z01` `.z02` `.zip`

If you already have a working code to read a zip archive, extending it with the ability to read a multiple-file archive should be simple, please refer to:

http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

> 8.2.1 File splitting is a newer derivation of spanning.
>   Splitting follows the same segmentation process as
>   spanning, however, it does not require writing each
>   segment to a unique removable medium and instead supports
>   placing all pieces onto local or non-removable locations
>   such as file systems, local drives, folders, etc.
>
> 8.3.3 Split ZIP files are typically written to the same location
>   and are subject to name collisions if the spanned name
>   format is used since each segment will reside on the same 
>   drive. To avoid name collisions, split archives are named 
>   as follows.
>
> Segment 1   = filename.z01
>   Segment n-1 = filename.z(n-1)
>   Segment n   = filename.zip
>
> 8.3.4 The .ZIP extension is used on the last segment to support
>   quickly reading the central directory.  The segment number
>   n should be a decimal value.

Comment: Like Sulthan say just take all Data of files and concat in one file (in order) and just unzip this new file thats work fine.
Thanks to Sulthan.